# Playframework 2.3.x JAVA + JPA + MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, playframework

I am using playframework 2.3.x and Java. For my project i would like to connect with mysql and used JPA, the connection work fine (i think) but when i try to create an model user i have this error :

```
[error] C:\Users\lpiroche\Documents\www\play_framework\play_sample1\modules\core
\app\models\User.java:3: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
[error] import javax.persistence.Column;
[error]                         ^
[error] C:\Users\lpiroche\Documents\www\play_framework\play_sample1\modules\core
\app\models\User.java:4: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
[error] import javax.persistence.Entity;
[error]                         ^
[error] C:\Users\lpiroche\Documents\www\play_framework\play_sample1\modules\core
\app\models\User.java:5: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
[error] import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
[error]                         ^
[error] C:\Users\lpiroche\Documents\www\play_framework\play_sample1\modules\core
\app\models\User.java:6: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
[error] import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
[error]                         ^
[error] C:\Users\lpiroche\Documents\www\play_framework\play_sample1\modules\core
\app\models\User.java:7: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
[error] import javax.persistence.*;
[error] ^
[error] C:\Users\lpiroche\Documents\www\play_framework\play_sample1\modules\core
\app\models\User.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
[error] @Entity
[error]  ^
[error]   symbol: class Entity
[error] C:\Users\lpiroche\Documents\www\play_framework\play_sample1\modules\core
\app\models\User.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
[error] @Table(name="users")
```

The play documentation is poor in example to connect to mysql database, i read tuto, post but i don't find a solution. i think i forget something in the persistence.xml file but i don't know what.

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(  
  javaJdbc,  
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final",  
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
)
```

**application.conf**

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password=""    
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
```

**persistence.xml**

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"  
version="2.0">  
  <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>  
    <properties>  
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />  
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"></property>
    </properties>  
  </persistence-unit>  
</persistence>
```

In the examples i find differentes configurations :

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"></property>
```

or

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />  
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
```

I don't know which one is the most appropriate

Comment: That's odd, Hibernate should have that as dependency... Try to run `./activator update` and try again. If you get the same result try to add `"org.hibernate.javax.persistence" % "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api" % "1.0.1.Final"` to your libraryDependencies in build.sbt and then run `./activator update`

Answer (score 2):

i found my problem. Maybe an another person could met a similar issue so i will explain it.

My project is divided in 3 subprojects : core, common, subproject1 for example

1. core = common class and api code
2. common = common module(popins, footer, header...) it could be contain views and controllers
3. subproject1 = site or admin module

common depends on core and subproject1 depends on common. My main project(root) depends on common and subproject1 and agregate them

**build.sbt**

```
name := "sample"

version := "1.0"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(  
  javaJdbc,  
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final",  
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava) 
                    .aggregate(common, subproject1 )  
                    .dependsOn(common, subproject1 )                 

lazy val core = (project in file("modules/core")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

lazy val common = (project in file("modules/common")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(core)
lazy val subproject1 = (project in file("modules/subproject1 ")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(common)
```

The problem appear when a try to create my User class in the **core** subproject (package core.app.models.datas), apparently as core is not aggregate directly in my root project the javax.persistence package are not imported. 
If i create a User class in common or subproject1 i have no problem.

To fix the problem i create a build.sbt file with the good dependencies :

**.../core/build.sbt**

```
name := "core"
version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(  
  javaJdbc,  
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final",  
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
)
```